# Why is the following error is showing while trying to add training set for CNN?

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

```
training_set = training_datagen.flow_from_directory("dataset\training_set\",
                                                    target_size=(64,64), 
                                                    batch_size=32, 
                                                    class_mode='binary')
```

File "", line 1
training_set = training_datagen.flow_from_directory("dataset\training_set",
^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you defined the path to your folder. In Windows `\` is an escape character, so it may return the error if you have `C:\Users\`. To avoid the error add one more `\` to become `\\`.